# Wait for a request to return a component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a component to protect the routes. What I am trying to do is check if the token is valid.

If it is valid I put the state of customer (isAuth) in redux to true. Default customer.isAuth is false.

I would like to wait for the request to be resolved to be able to analyze if the token is valid and once the verification is finished, return one component or another.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
import {
  selector as customerSelector,
  actionCreators as customerActions,
} from "@features/customer";
import Login from "@pages/login";
import API from "@api";

export const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const { customer } = useSelector((state) => customerSelector(state));
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [cookies] = useCookies();

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkToken = async () => {
      dispatch(customerActions.fetchCustomerValidTokenRequested());
      const { customer } = await API.isValidCustomerToken(
        cookies.jwt_ecommerce
      );
      if (customer) {
        dispatch(
          customerActions.fetchCustomerValidTokenSuccess({
            emailAddress: customer.emailAddress,
            firstName: customer.firstName,
          })
        );
      }
    };

    if (!customer.isAuth && cookies.jwt_ecommerce) {
      checkToken();
    }
  }, []);

  return customer.isAuth ? children : <Login />;
};
```

Comment: You could set a `loading` flag to true when you kick off the API request and remove it again upon completion. While `loading` is true your component shows a spinner or returns null. Or you could leave the default `isAuth` value undefined instead of explicitly false, and predicate the logic above on the presence of an isAuth value.

Answer (score 0):

```
function waitsync() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve("resolved");
      }, 1500);
    });
  }
```

Is what I used to wait while authenticating tokens.

```
    const result = await waitsync();
```

To call it.